# Hard to understand JSONPath containing [?]

Tags: json, jsonpath

In a legacy system I found this JSONPath :
`$['data']..['rels'][?]['persons'][*]`
I am confused by `[?]`,
as I am trying to rebuild the expected JSON that should by like (but it's not) :

```
{
  "tag1": ["VALUE1"],
  "data": [
    {
      "tag2": "VALUE2",
      "rels": [
        {
          "persons": [
            {
              "uid": "uid12"
            }
          ],
          "tag3": {
            "tag4": "tag4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I used https://jsonpath.com/
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to be confused by this. It's not valid JSON Path syntax.  It's an extension syntax supported by [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) (a JavaScript implementation) that they call "Filter Predicates."  You can read about it in the project's readme.

I and a few others have been working on writing an [official specification](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base) for JSON Path, and I brought this up recently after having seen another question around it.  This kind of confusion is something we aim to avoid.